# cocos2dx Undefined symbols for architecture i386: Error

Tags: cocos2d-x

Just now i have created a cocos2d-x project on my mac, Iam using ios version project for development. Iam new to cocos2dx and cpp. When i have first run the project in Xcode its perfectly run's fine. But When i add a touches methods in HelloWorldScene.h file its showing the Error as i run the project. what i have added is after include i have added the namespace cocos2d and after the static method CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld); i have added touch event method,

```
virtual void ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event);
```

When i build and run the project iam getting a error, the error is.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "HelloWorld::ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for HelloWorld in HelloWorldScene.o
  "non-virtual thunk to HelloWorld::ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for HelloWorld in HelloWorldScene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

For virtual function, in .h file, the definition is:

```
virtual void ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event);
```

Then in .cpp file, no need 'virtual':

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event){ ... };
```

I guess the problem is here.